# WooCommerce, how to load a custom javascript file while using Mystile theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi I have a WooCommerce plugin activated and a Mystile theme. I want to add a custom js file located at `mystile/includes/js/custom-script.js`. Ive read on how to add files through using `wp_enque_script` but it is not loading the js files when I view page source. 
I have this code block on functions.php of my current theme which is Mystile, which should have added my custom js file

```
function add_custom_assets(){
//Load masonry CSS and JS files
wp_enqueue_script('masonry', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'includes/js/custom-script.js',array('jquery'), '1', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_custom_assets');
```

the above code does not work and I cannot see my JS file in source. I really dont know what I am doing wrong. I even tried `wp_register_scripts` but its the same thing. 
The only change I did to the current theme was that I copied the `templates` folder from the woocommerce plugin directory to my current theme and renamed it `woocommerce` to override certain stuffs. Any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should specify unique handles (so stuff don't get overridden)

```
function add_custom_assets(){
    wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-script-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'includes/js/custom-script.js',array('jquery'), '1', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','add_custom_assets');
```

Comment: How was masonry not a unique handler. Anyways that did work. Cheers

Comment: The handle is different. If you enqueue a script with the same handle it might get overriden (depending on the order)..

Comment: Your theme might be loading the original masonry scripts after it loaded your script with the same handle.. always keep the handle unique and you shouldn't get into any problems. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is not a ideal solution but a hack and it does work. Enqueue the script as `wp_enqueue_style` rather than `wp_enqueue_script`. It does load the script but is a very dirty solution. Still the question is open though